# Pg_dump error in php .postgress 9.1

Tags: php, postgresql

I can not do the backup because windows throws error and I do not know how to solve it
I need to backup postgres using php and  windows. This is the command used.

```
**exec('pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:root@localhost:5432/sicanar > dbbackup.sql',$output);
print_r($output);**
```

But windows throws this error

The entry point for the icon_open procedure is not found in the C: \ WINDOWS \ System32 \ libintl.dll library

[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABYMm.png)

Comment: check, if libintl.dll  file exists in system32 folder.

Comment: libintl.dll exists in system32 folder

Answer (score 0):

I guess you copied the pg_dump.exe from an installation folder to some other location but did not copy all the dll's it needs. Now windows is trying to find them but find's a wrong version that is missing a function.

You will very likely need to copy the following dll's from the folder pg_dump was originally in

postgresql 9.4: intl.dll, libeay32.dll, libintl.dll, libpq.dll, ssleay32.dll and zlib1.dll.

postgresql 9.5 and 9.6: libeay32.dll, libiconv-2.dll, libintl-8.dll, libpq.dll, ssleay32.dll and zlib1.dll.

Comment: Libintl.dll is in system32 ... but in postgres this is libintl-8.dll and not libintl.dll

Comment: Files in folder postgresSQL libeay32.dll, libintl-8.dll, libpq.dll, ssleay32.dll y zlib1.dll.

Comment: Files not found in postgresSQL folder    intl.dll , libintl.dll

Comment: What version of postgres? Updated the answer.

Comment: 9.1 is fine but newer versions are in many cases more efficient but sometimes they are not 100% compatible with older application. Unfortunatly I do not have the list of dll's for 9.1 but as long as you copy the dll's from the same folder as where you got pg_dump.exe it should be fine. BTW is that the version of your postgres server or the version of pg_dump? The dll  libintl-8.dll in your postgresql folder suggests your server is newer and your pg_dump needs to be the same version or newer otherwise it won't know how to backup your server.

Comment: Is the version of postgres. Pg_dump installed with postgres

Comment: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\pg_dump.exe

Comment: files dll in    C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\     libeay32.dll ,libiconv-2.dll, libintl-8.dll, libpq.dll, libxml2.dll,libxslt.dll,  zlib1.dll, ssleay32.dll